# Открыть картинку на весь экран из Галереи

Tags: java, android, picasso

Разрабатываю приложение для ***Android***. В приложении галерея, подкачиваю картинки с сайта через библиотеку ***Picasso***. Картинки подгружаются в сетку небольших изображений(`GridView`, 3 столбца) и по задумке при нажатии на любую картинку нужно, чтобы эта картинка открывалась в новой активности на весь экран.

**Экран галереи:**

```
public class LindelofGalery extends Fragment {

    GridView grid;


    @Nullable    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.lindelof_galery, container, false);


        grid = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid); //  находим таблицу
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity().getApplication()));

        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LindelofGaleryFullImage.class);

                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);


            }
        });


        return rootView;


    }

    public static class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



        public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[] {

                "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Liquid-silicone-2-1.png",
                "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Liquid-silicone-2-1.png",
                "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Liquid-silicone-2-1.png",
                "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Liquid-silicone-2-1.png",
                "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Liquid-silicone-2-1.png",
                "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Liquid-silicone-2-1.png",
                "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Liquid-silicone-2-1.png",




        };
        private static final String[] IMAGE_URLS = IMAGES;


        public LayoutInflater inflater;

        Context c;

        ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            c = context;

        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return IMAGES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            final ViewHolder holder;
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                assert view != null;

                holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

                holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            Picasso.with(c)
                    .load(IMAGE_URLS[position])
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .fit()
                    .into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });

            return view;


        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
    }


}
```

**Код картинки на весь экран:**

```
public class LindelofGaleryFullImage extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lindelof_full_image);



        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id"); // получаем ID картинки
        LindelofGalery.ImageAdapter adapter = new LindelofGalery.ImageAdapter(this); 
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView); 
        imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(adapter.IMAGES[position])); 


        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); 
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


        }

    }


}
```

**При вылете приложения в логах:**

> 11-18 00:49:36.031 3571-3571/com.example.mish.biografy7 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mish.biografy7/com.example.mish.biografy7.Lindelof.LindelofGaleryFullImage}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Liquid-silicone-2-1.png"
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Liquid-silicone-2-1.png"
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
>                                                                                 at com.example.mish.biografy7.Lindelof.LindelofGaleryFullImage.onCreate(LindelofGaleryFullImage.java:32)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)

Раньше загружал картинки из `drawable`(без библиотеки ***Picasso***), получалось реализовать данную идею. Но тогда у меня данные были в int, сейчас в `String`(ссылки на сайт с картинками), и, судя по логам, ошибка как раз в этом.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать метод, чтобы получалось перейти на новую активность с картинкой на весь экран?

Comment: Здесь `Integer.parseInt(adapter.IMAGES[position])` вы пытаетесь извлечь из строки с адресом целое число, не знаю, зачем вы это делаете и как такое придумали, но у вас определенно ничего не получится. `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` - масло маслянное, метод `getActivity()` уже содержит необходимый контекст.

Comment: В текущем виде ваша проблема неисправима, так как вы пытаетесь работать с внешними ресурсами (из интернета), как с внутренними (которые имеют ID в классе R). Вам нужно сохранять изображение побайтно из интернета, а потом присваивать его в ImageView через преобразование скачанного в Bitmap (или тот же Glide/Picasso использовать)

Comment: Спасибо, что подсказали, в каком направлении двигаться, буду изучать дальше Picasso.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в этой строке:

```
imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(adapter.IMAGES[position]));
```

так как

```
// Можно делать так:
int count = Integer.parseInt("9"); 

// так делать нельзя:
int count = Integer.parseInt("jksnj34434kbjjda");
```

Вам правильно написали в комментариях, сначала надо загрузить картинку из интернета.

В ***Picasso*** (и подобных библиотеках), загрузка по url уже реализована, вам можно сделать так:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(adapter.IMAGES[position]).into(imageView);
```